# Show that $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)n} - \frac{9(-1)^n}{2\cdot 3^n}\right)x^n > 0$ for positive $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

How can one prove that $$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)n} - \frac{9(-1)^n}{2\cdot 3^n}\right)x^n > 0\,?$$

this inequality resulted after expanding the difference of two functions into a power series, graphing both functions with a graphing clearly shows one above the other for all $x > 0$ so this means the series must be positive as well, but I can't see how one could prove it analytically.

Also it may be useful to note that first two terms of the power series are zero, so the series can start at $n=4$.

Comment: the series doesn't converge for $x>3$; I suggest to go back to the original functions

Comment: @Conrad xpaul has given a neat answer, check it below.

Comment: precisely what I suggested (get the actual functions from the power series as all are known and use calculus) - my point was that the problem as stated is incorrect as the Taylor series do not converge beyond $3$

Comment: @Conrad thanks for your input, I completely forgot about restraining myself to the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)n} - \dfrac{9(-1)^n}{2\cdot 3^n}\right)x^n\\
&=&\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n-1}-\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n} - \dfrac{9(-1)^n}{2\cdot 3^n}\right)x^n\\
&=&-x+\ln(1+x)+x\ln(1+x)-\frac{3x^2}{2(3+x)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now
$$ f'(x)=\ln(1+x)-\frac{3x(6+x)}{2(3+x)^2}, f''(x)=\frac{x^2(9+x)}{2(1+x)(3+x)^2}. $$
Since $f''(x)>0$ for $x>0$, so $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and hence $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: I just realized that the well known $e^x > 1+x$ give us $x > \ln (1+x)$ with a $>$ not a $<$

Comment: I made a mistake. Let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: actually $f'(x) = \ln (x+1)-\frac{3\left(x^{2}+6 x\right)}{2(x+3)^{2}}$, you've mistaken the $-x$ for an $x$

Comment: I think it is right this time.

Comment: actually $f''(x) = \frac{x^{3}+9 x^{2}}{(x+1)(x+3)^{3}}$ but it doesn't make the final result wrong, thank you !